# Unicode Characters as a Column Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

Is there a way to assign a name from Unicode characters to a table column in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: You can use almost any character when creating an object. You could, foolishly, create one with the syntax `CREATE TABLE [What,...!? ¢×|\•[¥¶|¶]] Why're doing this... 1+1=7(no it doesn't)] (ID int);`. Why you would do so though is beyond me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the Unicode characters in Table name and Column Name using SSMS/TSQL square brackets.
for example :

```
   CREATE
   TABLE [t%] (c int)
```

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/154c19c4-95ba-4b6f-b6ca-479288feabfb/characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-table-name-amp-column-name-in-sql-server-?forum=databasedesign) will help.

Comment: @Eleonora you are welcome :)